# Matlab, how to save txt file, using save function, to save doubles as integers, but keep NaN

Tags: matlab

I'm using Matlab R2015a, and would like to save a matrix of doubles to a txt file. Some indices have `NaN` values. All other values, although `double` as format, are basically integers. There are no fractional values.

I would prefer if the saved values appeared as integers in the txt-file, except of course for the `NaN` values, which must remain `NaN`.

Example of my data, and how it should appear in the saved txt file:

```
NaN 81 272
NaN 787 314
778 174 606
427 720 677
```

I can do this by using `fprintf` in a loop, or with a single `dlmwrite`, but both methods are **very slow** for large matrices. Using the `save` function is **much faster**, but I don't know how to achieve the desired output (where doubles are written as integers, and preserving `NaN`'s) Also, the file size produced by `save`, is considerably larger, because of the formatting.

Example output from using the save function:

```
          NaN   8.1000000e+01   2.7200000e+02
          NaN   7.8700000e+02   3.1400000e+02
7.7800000e+02   1.7400000e+02   6.0600000e+02
4.2700000e+02   7.2000000e+02   6.7700000e+02
```

Below is a simple code example, using both `dlmwrite` (desired output, but slow), and `save` (undesired output, but fast).

```
% generate some data
m = round(rand(1000,3)*1000);
m(1:10,1) = NaN;

% dlmwrite method. Using dlmwrite to create header line and append the data.
% Output is as desired.
dlmwrite('file_by_dlmwrite.txt', 'column1 column2 column3', 'delimiter', '');
dlmwrite('file_by_dlmwrite.txt', m, 'delimiter', ' ', '-append');

% save method. Using dlmwrite only for the header line, and save function to append the data.
% Output is not as desired.
dlmwrite('file_by_save.txt', 'column1 column2 column3', 'delimiter', '');
save('file_by_save.txt', 'm', '-ascii', '-append');
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume you have a good reason for not writing to a binary using save?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `fprintf` *without* a loop?

```
m = round(rand(1000,3)*1000);
m(1:10,1) = NaN;
%
filename='file_by_fprintf.txt';
dlmwrite(filename, 'column1 column2 column3', 'delimiter', '');
fid=fopen(filename,'a');
fprintf(fid,'%7d %7d %7d\n',m');
fclose(fid);
```

Using a larger test case with `100000` instead of `1000` gives me

```
Elapsed time is 4.290399 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.207824 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.123091 seconds.
```

Where the first is your `dlmwrite`, the second is your `save`, and the third is mine.

Comment: Thank you!! I'm very happy with this! I don't know why, but I never realized `fprintf` could do it in one go. Also, I notice the transpose of the data, before writing.

Comment: @ctp, indeed, you need the transpose since `fprintf` accesses its variables in a column-major way. It's easy to remember if you imagine that it basically does `m(:)`, implying that you usually need that transpose.